# when generating random numbers, I get the same numbers

Tags: assembly, x86

I have a snippet of my code in which I want to highlight 10 random numbers in the console. So far I have been able to do this, the numbers are generated, but every time I get 10 of the same number

```
mov ecx, 10
myLoop:
push ecx

;--- randomize a number in the range 0-range ---
    call GetTickCount
    push eax
    call nseed
    push range
    call nrandom
    mov drawnNumber, EAX
;;;;    ................
;--- derivation of the calculation result ---
    push    EAX
    push    OFFSET messageNumber
    push    OFFSET buffer
    call    wsprintfA
    add ESP, 12
    mov rinp, EAX
;--- displaying the result ---------
    push    0 
    push    OFFSET rout
    push    rinp
    push    OFFSET buffer
    push    hout
    call    WriteConsoleA

pop ecx
loop myLoop
```

Comment: You do not want to reinitialize the random number generator in the loop. Move that to before the loop. As it is, the code likely reinitializes with the same tick since the cpu is running much faster than the tick count increments.

Comment: but when i move `call nseed` outside of the loop i get infinite loop

Comment: Did you move all 3 lines? Also check calling convention for `nseed` and `nrandom` as they may be cdecl so you might have to remove the arguments you pushed. In any case that's a different problem :)

Comment: Depending on your purpose and requirements, you might consider using the `rdrand` instruction. Simple and easy. (Obviously if your goal is to experiment and understand how random number generators work, that wouldn't be a suitable answer.)

Comment: Also, you could use a register other than ECX for your loop counter, so you don't need push/pop inside the loop.  [The `loop` instruction is slow on most CPUs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35742570/224132).